# How to make a BaseClass that extends React.Component, so that all my other classes extend BaseClass and can specify their own Props and State types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, generics, typescript

For example, in vanilla JS I could easily do something like this:

```
class BaseClass extends React.Component { ... }

class Foo extends BaseClass { ... }

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, someEl)
```

and it just works, no problem.

However, I can't seem to do such a simple thing in TypeScript. I tried to do

```
class BaseClass<P,S> extends React.Component<P,S> { ... }

interface IFooProps {...}
interface IFooState {...}
class Foo extends BaseClass<IFooProps, IFooState> { ... }

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, someEl)
```

but that fails with errors like

```
ERROR in ./src/app.tsx
(44,17): error TS2605: JSX element type 'Foo' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Property 'setState' is missing in type 'Foo'.

ERROR in ./src/app.tsx
(44,17): error TS2607: JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property

ERROR in ./src/Foo.tsx
(30,49): error TS2339: Property 'props' does not exist on type 'Foo'.
```

My question is, how do we extend `React.Component` in order to make a base class where child classes of the base class can still specify the types of their props and state, so that I can do

```
class Foo extends BaseClass<IFooProps, IFooState> { ... }
```

where `BaseClass` extends from `React.Component`?

Comment: Are you importing `React` in both `app.tsx` and `Foo.tsx`?

Comment: Hmmmm, after spending all night on it with no luck, it appears to be magically working. I do believe that what I'm doing in my above example is in fact how it is supposed to be done, right? I must've had a typeo somewhere. Since it's working now, I'm going to vote to close this.

Comment: While basarat has a good answer below, it is important to point out that react is built to use composition over inheritance: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html. If you find yourself needing to use inheritance, it is suggested you abstract out the pieces you want to re-use and then use composition to share that code/UI.

Comment: I mostly use composition when composing the UI, but in this case I really thought that a base class would be better, as basically all classes extend from it instead of React.Component. It's like a app-wide feature for all components. And it adds stuff on `this` which in my case I think is cleaner than `this.props` for things that really aren't HTML props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is perfectly fine:

```
class BaseClass<P,S> extends React.Component<P,S> { ... }
```

and works fine e.g. I use it to add custom behavior to my React components in alm : https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/5ff516f0212f75c7365a56104413d34dddcbf429/src/app/ui.tsx#L11